# Replace Product Names with a Loop

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento webshop with several products in it. All of them begin with the word **PRODUCT**,

**for example**

```
PRODUCT 001.
```

I want to replace the word **"PRODUCT"** with **"Article"**.

I tried to write a small script, but it's not working at all. Here is what I've got so far:

```
<?php
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
foreach($_productCollection as $_product)
{
     $name = $_product->getName();
     $new = str_replace("PRODUCT","Article", $name);
     $_product->setName($new);
     $_product->save();
};
?>
```

I did not really know how to run the script, so I added this into a CMS page and opened it:

`{{block type="core/template" template="script.phtml"}}`

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `Replacename.php` inside your magento root folder 
and write the below code in that file and then execute it with below URL http://www.yourdomain.com/Replacename.php

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); 
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
               ->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($_productCollection as $_product)
{   
     try
     {
        $name = $_product->getName();
        $new = str_replace("PRODUCT","Article", $name);
        $_product->setName($new);
        $_product->save();
     }
     catch(Exception $e){
          echo $e->getMessage();
     }
}
```

Comment: I have not enough reputation to upvote, I will do it as soon as i can :). Another thing, the function str_replace() only allows to replace "whole words". Is it possible to change single letters in a word?

Comment: you can use `substr()`

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm a bit confused right now. Sometimes, if i run the script, it works, and sometimes, nothing happens?